# alignment and constraint does not work in SwiftUI

Tags: iphone, ipad, swiftui, alignment

I'm just trying to use the segment control which work on both -iPhone and iPad devices.
Using SwiftUI, below is the code and screenshot, this code does not work for iPad and different versions of iPhone devices.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var favoriteColor = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack{
                Picker("What is your favorite color?", selection: $favoriteColor) {
                                Text("Red").tag(0)
                                Text("Green").tag(1)
                                Text("Blue").tag(2)
                            }
                            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                            .padding(.top,10)
                 }
            }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Attached screenshot[image]

iPad
[image]

Not sure, how to align this for any iPhone or iPad devices

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? What did you expect? I don't see any alignment in provided code. BTW, term *constraint* is not applicable in SwiftUI.

Comment: You only have the segmented control inside a horizontal stack with no items in it.  Since there are no other items in the app, the HStack automatically gets centered in the view. How are you expecting the code to work? How does it not work on certain devices? If you provide better samples and screen shots we can give better advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Your ipad view is not looking proper as you want Because you did not gave navigationViewStyle to your navigation View.

```
            NavigationView {
               HStack{
                   Picker("What is your favorite color?", selection: $favoriteColor) {
                                   Text("Red").tag(0)
                                   Text("Green").tag(1)
                                   Text("Blue").tag(2)
                               }
                               .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                               .padding(.top,10)
                    }
    }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Just add .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) at the end of your NavigationView.

Comment: this did not work for me

Comment: @sia, I have added screen shot from the app how it looks on ipad after adding .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())

Answer (score 1):

As [Namra Parmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18158095/namra-parmar) said you need to set (override) the default navigation style of the iPad, because, by default, views are stacked up on iPhone, but they become columns on the iPad.
Here are some devices with different screen sizes: iPhone SE 1st gen (4.0inch), iPhone 13 Pro (6.06inch), iPhone 13 Pro Max (6.68inch), iPad pro (12.9inch), when you set the navigationViewStyle to "StackNavigationViewStyle()".

[image]